# maven to auto pull dependencies test jar

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

How to fetch the tests.jars for the dependencies included in pom.xml without explicitly specifying the dependency on artifacts for test scope.
For ex: My pom.xml includes 'n' dependencies and most of which contains tests.jar as well. When I run mvn:test with this pom, I would like to grab these dependencies tests as well and run them (because the parent pom is the aggregator and want to run tests to ensure integration does not break things).
If I include the dependency on test artifact of these 'n' dependencies, and use maven-surefire-plugin with dependenciesToScan combination (as shown below), I am able to run the tests.
But this requires me to edit the pom.xml every time I build a test jar for dependency or add a new dependency.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <configuration>
        <dependenciesToScan>
            <dependency>group:artifact1</dependency>
            <dependency>group:artifact2</dependency>
        </dependenciesToScan>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
..
..
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
        <version>version</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact2</artifactId>
        <version>version</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
....
...
</dependencies>
```

Without adding explicit depenency on test artifacts, is it possible to automatically pull and run the dependencies's tests as well (of course not for all dependencies but for few that match a specific group Id)?

Comment: Your last edit didn't improve the result. Paste the XML, select it and then use the small "code" button above the editor to turn it into code.

Comment: I moved onto gradle to achieve this. It was a simple task configuration with ant JUnit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439082/gradle-to-run-tests-from-test-dependency-jars has details.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a sane strategy to me. The tests will already be run when each dependency is built.

Unless you created dependencies between the tests (like changing the order of JARs on the classpath will change the test result), running them again from a different project should not have any impact.

If your tests start to break or behave differently when the order of JARs on the classpath changes, then I suggest you look into your version control system and talk to the person who wrote that test.

**[EDIT]** Reply to the first comment below:

I've been there. What you describe is an integration test (IT). First of all, be really, really careful with them. ITs are brittle and a bottomless hole for resources. If you're not careful, you'll strangle yourself with your own work. See also: [Integration Tests are scam](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/integration-tests-scam).

After this disclaimer, here is my strategy to tame the beast:

1. Make sure that tests are independent. Always.
2. Create a new module which depends on the WAR module. This contains your ITs - it can see the whole world, can have it's own setup and config and it can deploy the WAR if necessary.
3. Remember that mistakes aren't random. [People always make the same mistakes over and over again.](http://www.fastcompany.com/28121/they-write-right-stuff) **This works in your favor for once.** So what you need to do is add tests that checks for bugs in the Spring config. The tests should load the spring config and do checks like: Are we seeing the beans that we expect? Are the correct overrides there? Are beans missing?

As you add tests, defect rates will go down since the tests will cover those areas where your team usually makes mistakes.

Comment: well my usecase is: Have a project with POM to build a war file. This war depends on 'n' java projects. All of the java projects are spring based with war project defining the spring bootstrap configuration. This root config includes the spring config from Java projects. When the war is built finally, I want to make sure nothing breaks w.r.t spring root config.

Comment: I understand. I was there as well. See my edits how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

First if we are talking about Unit tests the above setup does not make sense. You are ignoring the concept of Maven, cause every module should have it's unit tests within the module and they are run during the life cycle before the resulting jar file has been packaged.

The folder layout exactly looks like this:

```
  +-- pom.xml
  +-- src/
       +-- main
            +--- java (Production code)
       +-- test
            +--- java (Unit Test code)
```

So the given test code is intended to unit test the production code. That means that the unit tests will run during the build and packaging of that artifact and **NOT** after the packing. If that would be the case we are talking about integration tests which should be handled different.

A test-jar which you are using is intended for something different. It is used to have common classes which are used by several unit tests which give the opportunity to reuse code in unit tests.

Comment: please see my comment in reply to @Aaron response.

Comment: @Jack But this are integration tests. There you should create a separate module-it where you can use cargo to deploy the war file to Tomcat etc. or may be aquirillian to do integration tests on the resulting war in a real environment.